# How to retrieve ID field and append in a url to make a request in jQuery.

Tags: jquery

I am a newbe to java-script/ajax/json.  I have an assignment to create a Weather App. using jquery/Json. 
The app is suppose to have 3 predefined elements for the cities of "Miami", "Orlando", and "New York". and then a separate text field for user input. 
I am trying to write the function that will capture the "ID" of the  statement (up to this point has not worked), as well as when they enter a city in the text field pull that city name into a variable to use to create the link. I have searched the web for answers and downloaded tons of code to no avail.

The html page is this:
    
        
           **City**

```
    <tr>
    <td><strong>State</strong></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="txtState" /></td>

  </tr>

  </table>

    <input type="button" id="btnGetWeather" value="Get Weather Data">
    <br /><br />
    <div id="resultDiv">
    </div>

 <br/>

   <div class="weather-wrapper">
    <ul id="theMenu">
       <li><a href="#" class="menuLink" id="Orland, FL">Orlando, Florida</a> 

        <ul> 
            <li class="weather-place">Location: Orlando</li>
            <li class="weather-temperature">Temperature: </li>
            <li class="weather-min-temperature">Low Temperature: </li>
            <li class="weather-max-temperature">High Temperature: </li>
            <li class="weather-description">Description/Conditions: </li>



        </ul> 
    </li>

    <li><a href="#" class="menuLink" id="Miami, FL">Miami, Florida</a> 

        <ul> 

            <li id="cityname2">Location: Miami, FL</li>
            <li id="temp2">Temperature: </li>
            <li id="lowTemp2">Low Temperature: </li>
            <li id="highTemp2">High Temperature: </li>
            <li id="conditions2">Description/Conditions: </li>

        </ul> 
    </li> 

<li><a href="#" class="menuLink" id="New York, NY">New York, New   York</a> 
              <ul> 
                <li id="cityname3">Location: New York, NY</li>
                <li id="temp3">Temperature: </li>
                <li id="lowTemp3">Low Temperature: </li>
                <li id="highTemp3">High Temperature: </li>
                <li id="conditions3">Description/Conditions: </li>
            </ul> 
          </li>

        </ul>

    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

The start of my .js file is this: (please bear in mind I have re-written this 100 times or better to nothing working or breaking something else). I have searched and watched hours of YouTube videos but nothing has solved my problem. the below code is copied and pasted from this site as well as many others and I just can't get it to work.  I know this should be very simple. So thanks in advance for any suggestions or pointers to solve the problem.

js File:

```
$('.menuLink').click(function() {
   console.log('via $this: ' + $(this).index());
});

$('#theMenu').on('click', '.menuLink', function() {
    var index = $(this).parent().index();
    console.log('via parent: ' + index);
});
var set = $('.menuLink');
   set.click(function() {
   console.log('via set: ' + set.index(this));
 });


//function creates an expandable/collapsable menu.
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#theMenu").accordion({
     animate: false, 
     collapsable: true,
     autoHeight: false, 
     header: ".menuLink"
  });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnGetWeather').click(function () {
       var requestData = $('#txtCity').val() + ',' + $('#txtState').val();
       var resultElement = $('#resultDiv');


       $.ajax({
//url: 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weatherid=2172797&appid=df8d86d5da06a368ed1d839b7b126155',
                method: 'get',
                data: { q: requestData },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                resultElement.html('Weather: ' + data.weather[0].main + '<br/>' + 'Description: ' + data.weather[0].description);

            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I can't find #txtCity in HTML. Where is it?

Comment: I suggest to use the developer tools of your browser to see what is sent to server and what comes back.